# How export database with sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm creating migrations for my existing mysql database. I like to backup my target database before running migration.

Is there any sequelize-cli commad like `npx sequelize-cli db:backup`? Or any other methods?

I can't find it in [sequelize cli documentation](https://github.com/sequelize/cli)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

No there currently no support for this.

REF: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8257

Answer (score 0):

You can backup your db just by coping db file.